# How to append inputs with formik in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

So this may be something simple but I'm hitting a roadblock. I want to take in a form input but can't seem to figure out how to append the value correctly so its appending string is captured.

I'm using Formik with yup in react.

```
<InputGroup>
    <Field
      id="appended-input"
      name="domain_url"
      type="text"
      value={values.domain_url}
      className={
        "form-control" +
        (errors.domain_url && touched.domain_url
          ? " is-invalid"
          : "")
      }
    />
    <ErrorMessage
      name="domain_url"
      component="div"
      className="invalid-feedback"
    />
    <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
      .localhost
    </InputGroupAddon>
</InputGroup>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I just want to get the .localhost to be automatically added to the input items. for this field. I thought I could do something like value=({values.domain_url} + ".localhost") but that didn't seem to work and as you may already tell I am very new to javascript.

Thank you!

Full code below, I'm also having issues with datepicker displaying within the formik state, and then there's how to even get the values to push to my getTenant(function) to be passed to my api.

```
static propTypes = {
    addTenant: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  onSubmit = (values) => {
    values.preventDefault();

    this.props.addTenant(values);
  };

  render() {
    const {
      domain_url,
      schema_name,
      name,
      config,
    } = this.state;

    const TenantSchema = Yup.object().shape({
      domain_url: Yup.string()
        .max(255, "Must be shorter than 255 characters")
        .required("Client URL header is required"),
      schema_name: Yup.string()
        .max(255, "Must be shorter than 255 characters")
        .required("Client db name is required"),
      name: Yup.string()
        .max(255, "Must be shorter than 255 characters")
        .required("Client name is required"),
    });
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            domain_url: "",
            schema_name: "",
            client_name: "",
            config: [
              {
                date: "",
                Tenant_description: "",
              },
            ],
          }}
          // validationSchema={TenantSchema} this is commented off because it breaks         
         submittions
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
            setSubmitting(true);

            setTimeout(() => {
              alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
              resetForm();
              setSubmitting(false);
            }, 100);
          }}
        //onSubmit={onSubmit}

        >
          {({
            values,
            errors,
            status,
            touched,
            handleBlur,
            handleChange,
            isSubmitting,
            setFieldValue,
            handleSubmit,
            props,
          }) => (
            <FormGroup>
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <legend>
                  <strong>Create</strong> Tenant
                </legend>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Label for="normal-field" md={4} className="text-md-right">
                    Show URL
                  </Label>
                  <Col md={7}>
                    <InputGroup>
                      <Field
                        id="appended-input"
                        name="domain_url"
                        type="text"
                        value={values.domain_url}
                        onSubmit={(values) => {
                          values.domain_url = values.domain_url + ".localhost";
                        }} //this isn't working
                        className={
                          "form-control" +
                          (errors.domain_url && touched.domain_url
                            ? " is-invalid"
                            : "")
                        }
                      />
                      <ErrorMessage
                        name="domain_url"
                        component="div"
                        className="invalid-feedback"
                      />
                      <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
                        .localhost
                      </InputGroupAddon>
                    </InputGroup>
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Label for="normal-field" md={4} className="text-md-right">
                    Database Name
                  </Label>
                  <Col md={7}>
                    <Field
                      name="schema_name"
                      type="text"
                      className={
                        "form-control" +
                        (errors.schema_name && touched.schema_name
                          ? " is-invalid"
                          : "")
                      }
                    />
                    <ErrorMessage
                      name="schema_name"
                      component="div"
                      className="invalid-feedback"
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Label for="normal-field" md={4} className="text-md-right">
                    Name
                  </Label>
                  <Col md={7}>
                    <Field
                      name="name"
                      type="text"
                      className={
                        "form-control" +
                        (errors.name && touched.name
                          ? " is-invalid"
                          : "")
                      }
                    />
                    <ErrorMessage
                      name="name"
                      component="div"
                      className="invalid-feedback"
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FieldArray
                  name="config"
                  render={(arrayHelpers) => (
                    <div>
                      {values.config.map((config, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                           <FormGroup row>
                            <Label
                              md={4}
                              className="text-md-right"
                              for="mask-date"
                            >
                              Tenant Description
                            </Label>
                            <Col md={7}>
                              <TextareaAutosize
                                rows={3}
                                name={`config.${index}.tenant_description`}
                                id="elastic-textarea"
                                type="text"
                                onReset={values.event_description}
                                placeholder="Quick description of tenant"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                value={values.tenant_description}
                                onBlur={handleBlur}
                                className={
                                  `form-control ${s.autogrow} transition-height` +
                                  (errors.tenant_description &&
                                  touched.tenant_description
                                    ? " is-invalid"
                                    : "")
                                }
                              />
                              <ErrorMessage
                                name="tenant_description"
                                component="div"
                                className="invalid-feedback"
                              />
                            </Col>
                          </FormGroup>
                          <FormGroup row>
                            <Label
                              for="normal-field"
                              md={4}
                              className="text-md-right"
                            >
                              Date
                            </Label>
                            <Col md={7}>
                              <DatePicker
                                tag={Field}
                                name={`config.${index}.date`}
                                type="date"
                                selected={values.date}
                                value={values.date}
                                className={
                                  "form-control" +
                                  (errors.date&& touched.date
                                    ? " is-invalid"
                                    : "")
                                }
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  setFieldValue("date", e)
                                }
                              />
                              <ErrorMessage
                                name="date"
                                component="div"
                                className="invalid-feedback"
                              />
                            </Col>
                          </FormGroup>

                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  )}
                />
                <div className="form-group">
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                    className="btn btn-primary mr-2"
                  >
                    Save Tenant
                  </button>
                  <button type="reset" className="btn btn-secondary">
                    Reset
                  </button>
                </div>
              </Form>

              <Col md={7}>{JSON.stringify(values)}</Col>
            </FormGroup>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { addTenant })(TenantForm);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use **setFieldValue** if you want to customize the value

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void

You can add onChange

```
<Field
  id="appended-input"
  name="domain_url"
  type="text"
  value={values.domain_url}
  onChange={st => {
          let value = st.target.value;
          let suffix = ".localhost";
          let index = value.indexOf(".localhost");
          if (index > 0) {
            suffix = "";
          }
     //add suffix 'localhost' if it is  not already added
          props.setFieldValue("domain_url", value + suffix);
        }}

  className={
    "form-control" +
    (errors.domain_url && touched.domain_url ? " is-invalid" : "")
  }
/>;
```

But adding suffix is more preferable on onSubmit:

```
 onSubmit = {(values, actions) => {
       console.log('valuesbefore',values)
       values.domain_url= values.domain_url+ ".localhost"
       console.log('valuesafter',values)
       this.props.addTenant(values);
 };
```

Comment: neither option worked, onsubmit didnt append it nor did it return an error and changing it via on change gave off ---TypeError: Cannot read property 'setFieldValue' of undefined---setFieldValue had been brought in though.

Comment: seems like you have no props. Can you show Formik code as well?

Comment: I added the full code above, thank you. handling it at submit will be the best option as changing it through the value automatically adds the localhost to the value which doesn't look clean when having to change it. but I also have an issue with datepicker and then submitting it all if you want to try and take a crack at it.

Comment: I have provided the solution regarding datePicker in your another stackoverflow question.  Is there any problem regarding adding 'localhost' now?

Comment: oh the localhost does not actually get added with the code provided. it didn't work.

Comment: when I hit submit it still only shows up as "domain_url":"test",

Comment: I have updated onSubmit code. Can you show me the two console.log values that i have placed there?

Comment: the issue was i added you code to onsubmit within date picker instead of handling it within Formik, your solution works now ! thank you so much

Comment: Happy to help :) If it is solved, do accept and upvote the answer :)

Comment: @DipeshKC Can we pass onChange handler to `<Field onChange=>`? My understanding of Formik docs is that onChange handler is generated internally by Formik (which is the same as `formik.handleChange`)